# Passing a C# double array to a C++ function using CLI

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers, c++-cli

#### Right, what is needed sounds simple, but it is proving to be a real pain.

I have some GUI code in **C#** (note i've never used C# before but familiar with the syntax) and I have **C++** code which interacts with it using **CLI**.

In C#, I want to create an array of doubles, and send it to my C++ code. I'm using the code below as the means of passing an array, and this complies in isolation.

So from C# im passing in a double[] array into that function.

```
public ref class KernelWrapper
{
public: 
    static void ImageNoiseFilter(System::IntPtr imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, array<double>^ values);
```

What parameter type should I use to retrieve this array from the C++ side?

I've tried:

```
 MyFunction(double values[]){}
 MyFunction(double* values){}
 MyFunction(array<double>^ values){}
```

but none compile, usually with the message of "array is not a template" for the last one, and

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'RunImageNoiseFilterKernel' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'double *'
```

Any tips on how this achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

---

### For readability, I'm updating with code up here

## .cpp file:

```
void Bangor::KernelWrapper::ImageNoiseFilter(System::IntPtr imageData, int imageWidth,    int imageHeight, pin_ptr<double> pval){
    RunImageNoiseFilterKernel((Format24bppRgb*)((int)imageData), imageWidth, imageHeight); //If parameter would work, 4th argument would also be passed into this.
}
```

## C# code:

```
    double[] randomValues = new double[ARRAY_LENGTH]; //Array of random numbers
    KernelWrapper.ImageNoiseFilter(ptr, image.Width, image.Height, randomValues);
```

## The errors are:

```
Error   1   error C3824: 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>': this type cannot appear in this context (function parameter, return type, or a static member)
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'Bangor.KernelWrapper.ImageNoiseFilter(System.IntPtr, int, int, double*)' has some invalid arguments   
Error   4   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'double[]' to 'double*'
```

Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `cli` namespace to `array<double>^`? Like this: `cli::array<double>^ values`. Note that there also is a `std::array`. Perhaps a namespace clash because of `using namespace`-directives?

Comment: Do you mean as a parameter inside MyFunction()? `Error 1 error : name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name` is the result of that, followed by lots of expected a ")" errors. If you meant inside `ImageNoiseFiler` it makes no difference.

Comment: You don't really need to qualify with **cli**. The third signature you show is the correct one. What error message do you get when you use that one?

Comment: Are you certain you are compiling with the `/clr` option? I assume you're compiling from within VS. If so, the appropriate options should be buried somewhere in [your-project]->properties.

Comment: `error : name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name`
`error : expected an identifier`
`error : invalid combination of type specifiers`
`error : expected a ")"` those are the errors I get using the 3rd. /clr is being used, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Okay, so most attempts have failed for me; likely because I'm doing it wrong :P, but here is a solution which does work.

#### Imports:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
```

#### In the C# file, I create an array as so:

```
    float[] randomValues = new float[ARRAY_LENGTH]; //Array of random numbers
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(randomValues, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var randPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    KernelWrapper.ImageNoiseFilter(ptr, image.Width, image.Height, randPtr);
```

#### The definition of ImageNoiseFilter is:

```
static void ImageNoiseFilter(System::IntPtr imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, System::IntPtr randValPtr);
```

#### To obtain in my C++ function which expects a float pointer, I do this:

```
void KernelWrapper::ImageNoiseFilter(System::IntPtr imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, System::IntPtr randValues){
    RunImageNoiseFilterKernel((Format24bppRgb*)((int)imageData), imageWidth, imageHeight, (float*) ((int) randValues));
}
```

All this seems to work fine :), how good or safe this approach is I do not know, so anyone reading this should not assume its the "correct" approach, it just works.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what `gcroot` template is doing internally. I discovered it after reading your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [pin_ptr<> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1dz8byfh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert the managed array to a double*.  It pins the array so the garbage collector cannot move it while your native function is executing and accessing the array data.

```
#include <vcclr.h>                 // Declares cli::pin_ptr<>
using namespace cli;
#pragma managed(push, off)
#  include "unmanagedstuff.h"      // Declaration of MyFunction here
#pragma managed(pop)

...

        pin_ptr<double> pvalues = &values[0];
        MyFunction(pvalues, values->Length);
```

With the assumption that surely MyFunction() also needs to know the size of the array so I added an extra argument that passes the size of the array.  Not doing this is lethal, your native code is liable to destroy the managed heap integrity.  Note that the array will only stay pinned while *pvalues* is in scope so it is important that MyFunction() does *not* store the passed pointer.  If that's the case then you *must* copy the array.

Comment: Not sure I follow this I'm afraid. If I declare a function which takes in a pin_ptr, i get this error: `error C3824: 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>': this type cannot appear in this context (function parameter, return type, or a static member)` and if I put it in the C# code, it won't accept it.

Comment: You put that inside of your ImageNoiseFilter() function.  I can't guess where you might have put it.

Comment: I've updated the main post to highlight what I changed and what errors I get.